# Load all my images contained in only one DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, imagemap

I want my HTML page to load like normal, but I want one section of the page to only completely load after it has retrieved all images (static and rollovers) of that section.

I have this map I created using an image map and poly shapes. When a user rolls over a certain state, an entirely new map is loaded but it creates the appearance that only that section of that map is reloaded. I have not seen this done before because changing images or colors on an image map is not possible, so I had to do it this way.

Here is the link to the page: http://www.imaspy.com/unitedStatesMap.html

As you can see it takes a while for the rollover image to load over each state... but once they are all loaded the map works perfectly. I want all the images loads before the map appears. How can I do this with JavaScript?

Thanks!

Comment: Search the site for JavaScript Image preloader

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like others have already pointed out, the usual solution is to **preload** the mouseOver images. This is pretty basic, [RobG's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8722874/990877) should work fine.

However, since you have an image of the **entire** map for the mouseOver state of **each** state, that's not very friendly for your visitor's bandwidth. At 222 KB each, that amounts to `(50 × 222) / 1024 ≈` **10.8 MB** just to load the site. I would advise you to find another solution.

---

***Update:** I thought of a mistake in the solution I proposed. For a solution and the details, see the end of the answer.*

---

If you want to stick with you current solution as much as possible, here's what I would do:

> - Keep the base image and image map in place.
> - Create separate images for the mouseOver states, but cropped to just the states themselves (not the entire map).
> - Find the `top` and `left` coordinates for each mouseOver image (relative to the `#mapContent` div) and save these in a sort of **named collection** (which, in JavaScript, is just a plain object).

That object (or named collection) might look something like this:

```js
var states = {
  'newMexico': {
    top:  400,
    left: 300
  },
  'arizona': {
    top:  350,
    left: 250
  },
};
```

Your preloader could look like this:

```js
function preloadStates() {
    var state, img;
  
    for (state in states) {
        img = new Image();
        img.src = '/image/' + state + '.png';
        states[state].img = $(img).css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: states[state].top,
                    left: states[state].left
                });
    }
}
```

Because `for .. in` enumerates over the keys in an object, `state` is the name of the key (and thus the name of the state). We save a new `<img />` object (wrapped in a jQuery object) into the `state` collection (so we have access to it later) and we apply the `top` and `left` positions to it.

Now, to show those preloaded images to the user on mouseOver:

```js
var currentState = null;
var currentImage = null;

$("#imagemap area").hover(
    function () {
        var image;
        var state;
        
        currentState = $(this).attr("id");

        // Retrieve and show the preloaded Image:
        currentImage = states[currentState].img; // <-- wrapped in jQuery-object
        currentImage.appendTo('#mapContent');
    },
    function () {
        if (currentImage !== null) {
            currentImage.remove();
            currentImage = null;
        }
    }
);
```

This just appends the preloaded image to the `#mapContent` div. Don't forget to set `#mapContent`'s `position` to `relative`, or the position of the image will be relative to the document, not to `#mapContent`.

---

### Update

I just thought of a glaring mistake in my proposed solution:

Since the hover images will **cover the original image**, the `mouseOut` event would fire **as soon as the hover image is shown**.  Listening to the `mouseOut` event on the hover image instead of on the original image would circumvent this, but would result in a rectangular hit area.

Fortunately, there's a simple solution: add a **transparent** image on top of the original image (and the hover images) and apply the `imagemap` to that, instead.

Here is a proof on concept: http://jsfiddle.net/PPvG/t8prx/

A few pointers:

> - Once again, make sure `#mapContent` is positioned (either relatively or absolutely).
> - Position the transparent image absolutely at `top:0` and `left:0` and make it exactly as high and wide as the original image.
> - Make sure the transparent image has a z-index of at least 1 (and higher than the hover images):
>
>   #overlay { z-index: 1; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
> - Make the overlay transparent, either by making it a [1px transparent gif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacer_GIF) or by giving it `opacity: 0`. The former is more cross-browser safe.

My apologies for the oversight. :-)

Comment: there is not other solution aside from flash. Just a comment on what you said first. still reading your post.

Comment: wow that's a lot of work. I got to go over this tomorrow. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to pre-load images is like:

```
var preLoadedImages;

function preloadImages() {
  var img;
  var imageSources = ['01.jpg','02.jpg'];
  var i = imageSources.length;
  preLoadedImages = [];

  while (i--) {
    img = new Image();
    img.src = imageSources[i];
    preLoadedImages[i] = img;
  }
}
```

Note that the array of image objects must persist at least long enough for all the images to be loaded (and cached), hence the use of a global to store them. You might be able to use a closure instead. This also give you a handy collection of the images and their src properties of use in other functions (e.g. swapping images).

If you want to wait for all the images to load before doing something, you can create a flag for each image, then put a load listener on each image that cancels its flag. When all the flags are cancelled, all the images are loaded.

Comment: @Michael: `--` is the [decrement operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#--_(Decrement)). So `i--` returns `i` and then lowers the value of `i` by one. The `while` loop will run while `i > 0` and decrement `i` at each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Use the 'image' object. It would be something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var mouseoverImg = new Image(120, 90);
    mouseoverImg.src = "img2.gif";
    var mousedownImg = new Image(120, 90);
    mousedownImg.src = "img3.gif";
</script>
```

Let us assume that 'img1.gif' is already there in the document. The img2.gif is displayed during mouseover and img3.gif is displayed on mousedown. You can use addEventListener or other means of event registration and that's it.

Ok, here is a more elaborate example, but I leave it to you to fine tune it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"  
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
    <title>The 'image' Object</title>

    <style type="text/css">
    <!--

    -->
    </style>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        var mouseoverImg = new Image(120, 90);
        mouseoverImg.src = "img2.gif";
        var mousedownImg = new Image(120, 90);
        mousedownImg.src = "img3.gif";
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>The 'image' Object</h1>

    <p>
        <img id="img01" src="img1.gif" width="120" height="90"  
title="image 1" alt="Image 1" />
    </p>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var img01 = document.getElementById("img01");
        img01.addEventListener("mouseover", rolloverImg, false);
        img01.addEventListener("mouseout", rolloverImg, false);
        img01.addEventListener("mousedown", rolloverImg, false);

        var currentImg = "img1";

        function rolloverImg(e) {
            if (e.type == "mouseover") {
                img01.src = mouseoverImg.src;
            } else if (e.type == "mouseout") {
                img01.src = "img1.gif";
            } else if (e.type == "mousedown") {
                img01.src = mousedownImg.src;
            }           
        }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

You can use some random button-like images which you can download from somewhere; make sure they are named "img1.gif", "img2.gif" and "img3.gif". This example is only a demonstration. You need to adapt it for your needs.

Comment: How does this help me load the image faster? This is just an alternate way of displaying the roll over image.

Comment: This way you load the additional images that are displayed on mouseover and/or mousedown along with the rest of the page. These additional images are not displayed until the user moves the mouse over the target image, but they are ready to be displayed as soon as that happens i.e. it won't go to the server to load the image at that time. Basically, you are pre-loading the images here.

Comment: Okay. I've never see this image object before. How would apply this to my HTML? Can you edit the code a bit so I can see how exactly to get it to work?